# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 What's Going Wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to code this program to read 6 values from the command line as coordinates and use these coordinates to calculate the area and perimeter of the triangle formed.

However, I'm getting this error message when running the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at geometry.ThreePoints.main(ThreePoints.java:26)
```

What's going wrong?

My Code with the error message:

[image]

Comment: Might be a silly question but have you passed anything into `args`?

Comment: Did you pass the argument while running in eclipse ?? I guess you missed this plz follow this http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/cmd.pdf

Comment: *Please* don't post screenshots of your code. Text is much easier for humans and computers alike to read.

Answer (score 1):

This programm doens't read from command line, it reads the start arguments. which i guess are not there.

edit:
an example for reading from the command line, you'll find [at the oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html)

Answer (score 1):

you are running your program without any argument in `eclipse`.

go to `run > run configuration` and add arguments:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `args.length` to determine the number of arguments before you read them.

```
if (args.length < 6) {
  System.out.println("Number of argument too small. Must be 6, but was "+ args.length +".");
}
```

You've probably made a mistake entering the arguments. You should always check the number of array elements before you access them!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not passing parameters while trying to run the program.

Go to run configuration in eclipse and add your parameters there. this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `eclipse` Go To `RunAs-->Run Configurations.. --> Arguments --> Program Arguments`.

Put there `arguments whitespace separated`.

Use `args.length` to check the `length` of `arguments`.